# Python pillow automated image editing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to pillow but as far as my knowledge goes I understand that pillow can help me. I want to automatically edit picture that a user uploads.

for example automatically edit this [image] or [image][image]

to this [image] or this [image] accordingly.

Is it possible with pillow? how should i tackle/approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `.blend` method.

For two images `image1` and `image2`:

```
from PIL import Image
image1 = Image.open(path1)
image2 = Image.open(path2)
new_image = Image.blend(image1, image2, alpha)
#save / do stuff
```

Alternatively, if you want to specify coordinates:

```
 image1.paste(image2, (x, y), mask)
```

Comment: I will try it but i do not know how to do if the function needs to resize properly one of the items.